# Jquery toggle li based on data-max and data-min with validation message

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

- I want to be able to SELECT an image (li), the number of select items depends of data-max and data-min on the (main div)

the problem is in the chosen function I'm removing the checked status and selected class of an item in the list

so it works until I select the top one then it gets confused
I need to change the validation to just return true or false

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/346/

**JS**

```
(function () {

    var mobileForms = (function () {

        return {

            model: {
                selection: {
                    validate: {
                        test: function (e) {
                            var that = this,
                                modelSelector = $('.divModelOptions'),
                                chosen = $('input:checked', modelSelector),
                                messages = $('.message', modelSelector),
                                minMessage = $('.min', modelSelector),
                                maxMessage = $('.max', modelSelector);


                            if (typeof (that.messageDisplayTime) !== 'undefined') clearTimeout(that.messageDisplayTime);
                            if (chosen.length >= that.min && chosen.length <= that.max) {
                                messages.slideUp(200);
                                return true;
                            } else if (chosen.length > that.max) {

                                if (that.max > 1) {
                                    maxMessage.slideDown(400, function () {
                                        that.messageDisplayTime = setTimeout(function () {
                                            maxMessage.slideUp(200);
                                        }, 3000);
                                    });

                                    if (typeof (e) !== 'undefined') e.preventDefault();
                                    return false;
                                } else {
                                    chosen[0].checked = false;
                                    chosen.parents('li').removeClass('selected');
                                    return true;
                                }

                            } else {
                                minMessage.slideDown(400);

                                return 'fail';
                            }
                        },
                        init: function () {
                            var modelSelector = $('.divModelOptions'),
                                html = '';

                            this.min = parseInt(modelSelector.attr('data-min'), 10);
                            this.max = parseInt(modelSelector.attr('data-max'), 10);

                            html = '\
                                <ul class="validation">\
                                    <li class="message min">' + modelSelector.attr('data-min-msg') + '</li>\
                                    <li class="message max">' + modelSelector.attr('data-max-msg') + '</li>\
                                </ul>';

                            modelSelector.prepend(html);
                        }
                    },
                    bindHandlers: function () {
                        var that = this,
                            modelSelector = $('.divModelOptions'),
                            chosen = $('input:checked', modelSelector);
                        var max = parseInt(modelSelector.attr('data-max'), 2);

                        $('input', modelSelector).click(function (e) {
                            var parent = $(this).parents('li');

                            if (that.validate.test(e)) {
                                if (parent.hasClass('selected')) {
                                    parent.removeClass('selected');
                                } else {
                                    parent.addClass('selected');
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        if (chosen.length) {
                            chosen.parents('li').addClass('selected');
                            that.validate.test();
                        }

                        $('form').submit(function (e) {
                            if (!that.validate.test() || that.validate.test() === 'fail') e.preventDefault();
                        });
                    },
                    init: function () {
                        this.validate.init();
                        this.bindHandlers();
                    }
                },
                nextButton: {
                    bindHandlers: function (button) {
                        button.one('click', function () {
                            mobileForms.showNextStep();
                        });
                    },
                    create: function () {
                        var nextCommandText = $('.divModelOptions').data('nextcommand');

                        // TODO: Next button should start off grey and become blue once a model is selected.
                        var button = $('<input type="button" value="' + nextCommandText + '" class="next-button">');

                        $('.divModelOptions').append(button);
                        this.bindHandlers(button);
                    },
                    init: function () {
                        this.create();
                    }
                },
                init: function () {
                    this.selection.init();
                    this.nextButton.init();
                }
            },
            validation: {
                focusOnError: function (messages) {
                    var message = $(messages[0]);
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: message.offset().top - 100
                    }, 500);
                },
                init: function () {
                    var visibleMessages;
                    $('form').submit(function () {
                        visibleMessages = $('.validation-message:visible, .validation .message:visible');
                        if (visibleMessages.length) {
                            mobileForms.validation.focusOnError(visibleMessages);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            init: function () {
                this.model.init();
                this.validation.init();
            }
        };

    })();

    $(function () {
        mobileForms.init();
    });

})();
```

Comment: What's your question? I honestly can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: Separately: Including all relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link (not even to jsFiddle, although a fiddle is a nice *addition*). Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: my code is too long. so I thought fiddle would help.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder could you help please?

Answer (score 0):

The code in question was rather difficult to follow as there were a lot of functions that are not really part of the question. It was also confusing having the error message element automatically hide, especially since multiple `setTimeout()` functions can be attached by clicking many times.

It helps to see what is happening by setting your CSS as:

```
.divModelOptions input {
    display: block;
}
```

The problem only occurs when `data-min="1"` and `data-max="1"` because of the `else` alternative:

```
if (that.max > 1) {
} else {
    chosen[0].checked = false;
    chosen.parents('li').removeClass('selected');
    return true;
}
```

which is entered since `that.max === 1` so the 2<sup>nd</sup> clicked item always results in the *first* `<input>`'s *checked* attribute being set to false, regardless of which item was clicked and then **all** `<li>` parents having the `selected` class removed. However, since you `return true;` then the calling code logic `if` condition is satisfied.

```
if (that.validate.test(e)) {
    if (parent.hasClass('selected')) {
        parent.removeClass('selected');
            //remove check status to input
    } else {
        parent.addClass('selected');
        //add check status to input
    }
}
```

which adds the `selected` class to the newly selected `<li>`.

Note, you get different inconsistent behaviour depending on if the first `<li>` selected **is** the first one selected. If you select the 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup> or 4<sup>th</sup> first.

I have tried to reduce the code in my answer to just address the problem of of showing a message if the number of selected items is under or over the defined range. So it might not be exactly what you are after but it should be a (hopefully) more simplified place to start.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqPKN/1/)

**JavaScript**

```
(function () {
    var mobileForms = (function () {
        return {
            model: {
                selection: {
                    validate: {
                        inRange: function (e) {
                            var self = this,
                                chosen = $('input:checked', self.modelSelector),
                                minMessage = $('.min', self.modelSelector),
                                maxMessage = $('.max', self.modelSelector);

                            if (chosen.length === 0 || (chosen.length >= self.min && chosen.length <= self.max)) {
                                self.validation.slideUp(200);
                            } else {
                                maxMessage.toggle(chosen.length > self.max);
                                minMessage.toggle(chosen.length < self.min);
                                self.validation.slideDown(400);
                            }

                            return chosen.length <= self.max;
                        },
                        init: function () {
                            this.modelSelector = $('.divModelOptions');
                            this.validation = $('.validation', this.modelSelector);
                            this.min = parseInt(this.modelSelector.data('min'), 10);
                            this.max = parseInt(this.modelSelector.data('max'), 10);
                            this.validation.slideUp();

                            $('.min span').text(this.min);
                            $('.max span').text(this.max);
                        }
                    },
                    bindHandlers: function () {
                        var self = this;

                        $('input', this.modelSelector).click(function (e) {
                            var parent = $(this).closest('li');
                            parent.toggleClass('selected');
                            if (!self.validate.inRange()) {
                                parent.removeClass('selected');
                                return false; // stop checkbox receiving event
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    init: function () {
                        this.validate.init();
                        this.bindHandlers();
                    }
                },
                init: function () {
                    this.selection.init();
                }
            },
            init: function () {
                this.model.init();
            }
        };

    })();

    $(function () {
        mobileForms.init();
    });
})();
```

and for completeness…

**CSS** (identical to question)

```
.divModelOptions input {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    float: left;
}
.divModelOptions label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.divModelOptions li.selected {
    border:1px solid red
}
.divModelOptions .validation li {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML** (play with data-max and data-min to see different examples)

```
<div data-max="2" data-min="2" class="divModelOptions">
    <ul class="validation">
        <li class="message min">At least <span></span> should be selected</li>
        <li class="message max">No more than <span></span> should be selected</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="Model" value="Model" name="Model" /><span rel="Model">Model</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="Model2" value="Model2" name="Model2" /><span rel="Model2">Model2</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="Model3" value="Model3" name="Model3" /><span rel="Model3">Model3</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="Model4" value="Model4" name="Model4" /><span rel="Model3">Model4</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```